# Text filtering in listview from Edittext Android

Tags: android, filter, android-listview, android-edittext, autosuggest

I have a list of cities(around 2500 of them). I want the user to get auto suggestions when he types in the edittextbox from that list. How is this achieved? I have searched Google through and through but cannot find any tutorial about this. Would really appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AutoCompleteTextview, here is a tutorial from the development site (bottom of the page). http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) to achieve this.

The following code snippet shows how to create a text view which suggests various countries names while the user is typing:

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I want to do this slightly differently. I have an adapter for a list of top 10 cties(this is a static list). Now when the user types in the edittext box, I want the filter from the other list of cities that I have. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Write a custom adapter and pass that to the AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: what is the advantage of using AutoCompleteTextView over an edittext and a listview and passing the typed text to the filter of the list's adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[**Filter**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html)" for searching from your other list.
Implement your own filter [MyFilter extends Filter] and override "FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix)" and "void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results)" methods to implement your own searching logic on your own data (country list).

Add a getMyFilter() method in your adapter which will return a "new myFilter"
Add a "TextWatcher" to your "EditText"
Inside "onTextChanged()" method of the TextWatcher, get your filter by calling myAdapter.getMyFilter()". On that filter, call "myFilter.filter(myTypedString)".

After filtering "**void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results)**" method will get called. Inside that, change your actual adapter data to refresh your UI.